# Blank line after defined paragraph

Tags: context, paragraphs

As you can see in the following code, I have a chapter definition which is always followed by one or several scenes. The heading of the scenes does not show any title, but instead two blank lines (the title will be shown in a table of contents).

I have created a paragraph definition which typesets the location of the scene, to use it each time a scene changes location. I wish to leave a blank space between the paragraph and the text of the scene, but I have been unable to do so.

```
\setuppapersize[A5]

% Chapters
\define[2]\CustomChapter{\dontleavehmode\framed[frame=on,width=broad,align=middle]{#1.\\#2}}

\setuphead [chapter]
           [after=,
            before={\blank[force,line]},
            command=\CustomChapter]

% Scenes
\definehead[scene][section]

\setuphead
  [scene]
  [placehead=empty,
   number=no,
   before=,
   after=,
   insidesection={\blank[2*line]}
  ]

% Location
\startsetups[paragraph:location]
  \setupalign[flushright]
\stopsetups

\defineparagraph
  [location]
  [style=italic,
   after={\blank[line]},
   setups=paragraph:location]

\showgrid

\starttext

\startchapter[title={One}]

\startscene[title={Karl llega a Dead Man Creek}]

\startparagraph[location]
South of Indiana, United States

March 1948

\stopparagraph

This is Chapter One, and you should see one line between the location and this text.

Each scene typesets two blank lines in its inside section.
\stopscene

\stopchapter

\startchapter[title={Two}]
\startscene[title={This is a scene}]
This is Chapter Two, and this scene typesets, again, two lines in its inside section.
\stopscene
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

Comment: A full MWE needs the \documentclass etc.  (you have no idea how many packages one would have to try to find the right ones).  I take it \medskip didn't work?

Comment: @JohnKormylo The document *is* a MWE; it is in ConTeXt, not LaTeX.

Comment: Indeed, it is a ConTeXt MWE, I should have mentioned it in the question, although I have tagget it as such, the tags are not enough.

Comment: `paragraph` environments do not use `before` and `after` keys. They are primarily meant to tag paragraphs for XML/XHTML export. If you need something to alter the display, why not use `framedtext` (that has the advantage of not splitting across pages?

Comment: I am going to try framedtext. I was also considering writing my own command for typesetting the location, but framedtext seems to fit the bill perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off using simply `\definestartstop`.  Paragraphs don't seem to be the right tool for what you are doing.  Basically you can use a custom start-stop as a drop-in replacement with the benefit that the `after` value works.

```
\definestartstop
  [location]
  [style=italic,
   after={\blank[line]},
   setups=paragraph:location]
\prependvalue{stoplocation}{\par}
```

The last line also smuggles a `\par` before `\stoplocation` so you can omit the extra blank line after March 1948.  I've also modified your document to adhere a little better to “the ConTeXt way”.

```
\setuppapersize[A5]

% Chapters
\starttexdefinition unexpanded CustomChapter #1#2
  \dontleavehmode
  \startframed[frame=on,width=broad,align=middle]
    #1.\\#2
  \stopframed
\stoptexdefinition

\setuphead
  [chapter]
  [after=,
   before={\blank[force,line]},
   command=\CustomChapter]

% Scenes
\definehead
  [scene]
  [section]
  [placehead=empty,
   number=no,
   before=,
   after=,
   insidesection={\blank[2*line]}]

% Location
\startsetups[paragraph:location]
  \setupalign[flushright]
\stopsetups

\definestartstop
  [location]
  [style=italic,
   after={\blank[line]},
   setups=paragraph:location]
\prependvalue{stoplocation}{\par}

\showgrid

\starttext

\startchapter[title={One}]

  \startscene[title={Karl llega a Dead Man Creek}]

    \startlocation
      South of Indiana, United States

      March 1948
    \stoplocation

    This is Chapter One, and you should see one line between the location and this text.

    Each scene typesets two blank lines in its inside section.
  \stopscene

\stopchapter

\startchapter[title={Two}]
  \startscene[title={This is a scene}]
    This is Chapter Two, and this scene typesets, again, two lines in its inside section.
  \stopscene
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```